# How do I wrap a label in a div within a class to modify it?

Tags: css

I'm looking for the method to put a label and text in a div, within a class.

I have this html:

```
<div class="awpcp-subtitle">Contact Information</div>
<a href="https://adsler.co.uk/wp-user-test-dashboard- 
2/awpcp-reply-to-ad/13/madame-bovary/">Contact 
Anonymous</a>
<br/><label>Phone:</label> 7576XXXXXX
<br/><label>Location:</label> London, UK

</div>
<div class="showawpcpadpage"><label>Price:</label> 
<strong>£ 3.00</strong></div>

<div class="fixfloat"></div>
```

I want to put the label 'phone' within a div class and, if necessary, the text after it in a div class.

Basically the aim of this is to be able to select the label 'phone' and the text after it, and give it a background color.

I don't know where I would insert it in given html, or even what it would lool like?

Im guessing somewhere after 'Anonymous,' 
so:

```
Anonymous</a> div class="Phone:"><label>Phone:>. 
</label>
```

and then continuing with existing code:

```
<br/>label><Phone:></label>7576XXXXXX 
<br/>..........
```

Comment: `<br/><div class="foobar"><label>Phone:</label> 7576XXXXXX</div>` …?

Comment: Sorry, but this is so extremely low-level, that you should really go work through some beginner’s tutorials first, IMHO.

Comment: Thank you for your help. And it may help others to find the correct way of doing it. Cheers.

Comment: What is a "div class"?

Comment: For example, see above html

Comment: Your terminology is a little mixed up. If you want to wrap the elements in a div _with a class_ you would simply write `<div class="some-class-name"><label>Phone:</label> 7576XXXXXX</div>`

Comment: @Turnip thank you. Is that after the first <br/> and before the second <br/> in above html?

Comment: @Turnip also using WordPress. How on earth do i locate the specific page to edit it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, I would suggest you go through some basics of HTML. This would be a good start: https://www.w3schools.com/html/

Now coming back to your question, you could enclose it like this:

```
<div class="awpcp-subtitle">Contact Information</div>
<a href="https://adsler.co.uk/wp-user-test-dashboard- 
2/awpcp-reply-to-ad/13/madame-bovary/">Contact 
Anonymous</a>
<div class="phone"><label>Phone:</label> 7576XXXXXX</div>
<div class="location"><label>Location:</label> London, UK</div>

</div>
<div class="showawpcpadpage"><label>Price:</label> 
<strong>£ 3.00</strong></div>

<div class="fixfloat"></div>
```

Here, I have removed the `<br>` because you were using it to make that `Phone` and `Location` display in separate lines. Since we are using `<div>` tags are block level element by default, the contents of it will be displayed in separate lines.

So, now you can change the color of those two boxes like this:

```
.phone{
    background-color: red;
}

.location{
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

And lastly you asked about how to do this in Wordpress. As you may already know Wordpress uses Themes, you have to check which one is your current theme (the one that is running in your website). This can be checked via visiting Wordpress Admin Panel --> Appearance --> Themes. You will see the current active theme's name in that page. Now you have to use an FTP Client or the File Manager in your cPanel to access the following the location: `/wp-content/themes/yourthemename/` in your server. Here, `youthemename` is the name of the theme that you noticed in the previous step.

Once you are in that folder, you would see a bunch on template files. I would suggest taking a close look at each file if you are unsure. Or its better you get a basic idea of Wordpress first before editing it. Take a look at this: https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/

Once you find out the template file has this HTML code you wanted to edit, simply open it and make the changes and save it. You are all done. If you are using any Cache plugins in your Wordpress, you might need to purge the cache if you don't see the changes when accessing the webpage.

That being said, my writeup might give you a small confusion. That's why I suggested to have a look at the basics first. Otherwise you have to hire someone who would be ready to do that specific changes for you.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks. What about about if the html is in a plugin itself, can i still edit it from cpanel?

Comment: Yes you can still edit from cPanel. It would be at `/wp-content/plugins/yourpluginname/` folder. But just keep in mind, if you edit the file there, next time you update that plugin, it would probably overwritten. Instead check the plugin's documentation and see if they provide any hooks. If so you can use it in your `functions.php` file of your theme to modify. Read more about here: https://wpshout.com/wordpress-hooks-actions-filters-work/

Comment: And also, will that div class 'phone' also select the mobile number: '07576XXXXXX'?

Comment: Because, basically, the end goal is to select them both and turn them into a button, represented by a phone icon, which links to dialing screen on mobile.

Comment: Yes the div is a parent container that holds both the label and the phone number. Think of it as a box. So `<div>` marks the starting of the box and `</div>` marks the end. Whatever you put in between that starting and ending tags will be within that box. Got the idea?

Comment: B so if I want to modify a div, I can insert it anywhere?

Comment: Insert what? Sorry, its not clear what you are asking now.